# str_replace/trim is not properly remove space from url

Tags: php

Well, I'm trying to sending message to my user based on my uploaded docx file. In this docx file there are few number exists. Like: 880167xxxxxxx, 880167xxxxxxx etc..

So to send sms i'm using following api link structure:

```
require_once("file.php");       
$docObj = new DocxConversion("$file");
$docText= $docObj->convertToText();
$foo = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $docText ); 

$sms =  "http://fahimit.com/smsapi.php?user=xxx&pass=xxx&phone=$foo
senderid=$sender&message=$msg";
$sms = file_get_contents($sms);
```

but it's not sending sms it's BECAUSE when i output **$foo** it's contain space  to left and right side of the number. So for that reason i used trim and preg_replace, str_replace but *NO LUCK.*

So what can i do to send sms without any space in this url **$sms** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have replaced space with space. Use this one:

```
$foo = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '', $docText );
```

Comment: Yep you have a space ' '  here needs to be ''

Comment: @chanchal118, one more question that is how do i know that how many entry are there in .docx file which is separated by , (comma)